# Keep middle 1024px and stretch side columns to fill the page?

Tags: html, css

How can I stretch the side divs to fill the page?

http://jsfiddle.net/p94vxnp2/1/

```
        <style>
            #page_body_table {
                display: table;
                width: 100%;
                vertical-align: center;
            }

            #page_body_left {
                display: table-cell;
                max-width: 100%;
                border: 1px solid black;
            } 

            #page_body_middle {
                display: table-cell;
                max-width: 1024px;
                border: 1px solid black;
            }

            #page_body_right {
                display: table-cell;
                max-width: 100%;
                border: 1px solid black;
            }

            @media screen and (max-width: 675px) {
                #page_body_left, #page_body_right {
                    display: none;
                }
            }
        </style>
        <center>
            <div id="page_body_left">
                left
            </div>
            <div id="page_body_middle">
                this is content of page
            </div>
            <div id="page_body_right">
                right
            </div>
        </center>
```

Comment: [Like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/p94vxnp2/4/)

Comment: @Vucko: I think the author wants `width:1024px`, not `max-width:1024px` for the middle.

Comment: Add `display:table` to `#page_body`. Also, keep your `<style>` in the `<head>`.

Comment: @Vucko, yes. Just chaning Max-Width on centered div to the Width, alone.

Comment: @Vuco, make answer, you got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make `display:table-cell` work, you have to put `display:table` to its parent.

In your case, add `display:table` to `#page_body`

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of all the `max-width`. Set the middle div as `width:1024px` and leave the sided divs without any`width`. They will fit automatically, as long as the wrapper div is `width: 100%;`

http://jsfiddle.net/p94vxnp2/5/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center div you have to do sth like this:

```
.center-div {
    Margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    Width: 500px;  for example
 }
```

You dont have to give divs on sides.

Comment: I need divs on both side of my centered div. the centered div must be static width, where sides must be flexible.

Comment: Left and right div make float: left and float: right.